# undefined when trying to access json data (ajax)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-models

***when i am trying to access data sent by django view from ajax i get undefined***

django view :

```
def GetTenders(request):
print request.POST
if request.method == 'POST':
    print request.POST.get('Page')
    page_num = int(request.POST.get('Page'))
    if page_num != 1:
        start = (page_num - 1) * 4
        objs = Tender.objects.all()[start:(start + 4)]
        return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', objs), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        objs = Tender.objects.all()[:4]
        print serializers.serialize('json', objs)
        return HttpResponse(serializers.serialize('json', objs), content_type='application/json')
else:
    print 'here'
    raise Http404
```

ajax:

```
 $.ajax({type:"POST",url: "GetTenders",dataType: "json",
                            data: { "Page": $(this).text() },content_type:'application/json',
                            success:function (data) {
                            for(x in data){
                                alert(x.model);}}})
```

debugging (response in browser) :

```
[{"model": "Register.tender", "pk": 1, "fields": {"Name": "First", "Kind": "Public Trend", "Category": 1, "Description": "my first bid ", "Created_on": null, "Modified": null, "Active": true, "Size": "S", "Ministry": 1}}]
```

alert messge :
[image: alert message]

any ideas :D

Comment: When you say `debugging (response in browser) :` what is the code you are using to print this, and where is it?

Comment: The returned data is an **array**, so you probably want `data[0].model`, not a `for ... in` loop.

Comment: @adeneo  tried the same :(

Comment: Works fine for me -> **https://jsfiddle.net/37ad4gdm/**

Comment: @ben432rew  from network in response this is the preview but can not get the data

Comment: @adeneo one minute please retrying

Comment: @adeneo wow thank you ✋

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`x` in your loop is an index of the array, so you want: `alert(data[x].model)`

see [for..in loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Also, if you're using Django 1.7+, please use [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

    ...

    else:
        objs = Tender.objects.all()[:4]
        return JsonResponse(objs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[ //<- Array 
    { //<- Object
        "model": "Register.tender",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": { //<- Object
            "Name": "First",
            "Kind": "Public Trend",
            "Category": 1,
            "Description": "my first bid ",
            "Created_on": null,
            "Modified": null,
            "Active": true,
            "Size": "S",
            "Ministry": 1
        }
    }
]
```

Accessing

```
var Obj = data[0];
Obj.model;
Obj.pk;
Obj.fields.Name
Obj.fields...
```

OR

```
data[x].model;
data[x].pk;
data[x].fields.Name
data[x].fields...
```